# How to pass an array reference as a parameter from assembly to a c++ function

Tags: c++, assembly, parameter-passing, masm, irvine32

I have two separate files in two Visual Studio 2012 projects.  One is MASM and the other is C++.  The MASM program is supposed to call the DisplayBoard function in the C++ program and needs to pass a reference to the array it is displaying.  I can't figure out what exactly I need to do to make this work.  The program was created in its entirety as a C++ program and works the way it should, but we are supposed to do the majority of coding in MASM and have minimal C++ functions, so we are trying to get these two files talking but are having issues.  Here are the skeleton codes for my MASM and C++ Files.  I am not sure if the C++ file needs a main, but it does compile without one.  Also, does the board array need to be declared in the C++ file if it is passed in as a parameter?  I think it doesn't, but am not sure.  I don't know if the array parameter is referenced correctly in the C++ file or not.

ASSEMBLY CODE:

```
TITLE HexAssemblyTest    (HexAssemblyTest.asm)
    .586
    .model flat,C

includelib kernel32.lib
includelib Irvine32.lib

ShowBoard PROTO near C, hexBoard:SDWORD

.data

board SDWORD 121 DUP (0)        ;array to hold the hex board


.code

main PROC 

    INVOKE ShowBoard, ADDR board    ;display board

Retn
main ENDP

END main
```

C++ CODE:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<stack>

using namespace std;

extern "C" void showBoard(int hex_array[]);



//Class DFS definition
class DFSAlgorithm{

public:
int board[121]; //board array


//function to display the board 
    void showBoard(int hex_array[]){

    //code here...

    }
//other functions...removed
    }

};//end DFSAlgorithm class
```

This is the error we get:

> ------ Build started: Project: HexAssembly, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   1>  Assembling HexAssemblyTest.asm...
>   1>HexAssemblyTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ShowBoard referenced in function _main
>   1>C:\Irvine\Examples\Assembly Hex programming\Debug\HexAssembly.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

I think I got it working correctly now... I modified DFSAlgorithm.cpp and DFSAlgorithm.h, compiled the C++ file and added DFSAlsogrithm.obj file to the project that has the assembly file.  They are now linking, but I'm getting a "deque iterator not dereferenceable" error message now when the C++ DFS search runs.  It worked fine while the entire program was in C++ so I'm not sure what I need to change to make it work correctly now that the array is being accessed from assembly file.  While stepping through with my debugger, I can see it IS generating adjacency arrays but I don't think the array is actually being accessed...

```
TITLE HexAssemblyTest    (HexAssemblyTest.asm)

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

printSomething PROTO C ;displays "GoobersX"
DFS PROTO C, color:BYTE, bptr:PTR DWORD, index:SDWORD

PDWORD TYPEDEF PTR DWORD

.data

bptr PDWORD board   
board SDWORD 121 DUP (0)        ;array to hold the hex board
arrayIndex SDWORD 0         ;variable to hold arrayIndex  


.code

main PROC 

INVOKE printSomething   ;tests if MASM and C++ are talking

Start:          
    CALL PlaceRed       ;prompt user to place a red stone
    CALL clrscr
    CALL crlf
    CALL ShowBoard      ;redraw the board

    ;check if there is a valid path using C++ DFS 
    PUSH EDX
    PUSH EBX
    PUSH ECX
    INVOKE DFS, 1, ADDR board, 0    ;color red, board address, arrayIndex 0
    POP ECX
    POP EBX
    POP EDX
    CMP EAX,1       ;if eAx == 1 winning path found
    JNE Continue        ;eAx != 1 no valid path...continue game

  ;the rest of this code removed for brevity

END_GAME:

Retn
main ENDP
```

My C++ header file looks like this:

```
C++ header file DFSAlgorithm.h

#ifndef DFSAlgorithm_H
#define DFSAlgorithm_H
extern "C" void printSomething();
extern "C" int DFS(int color, int hex_array[], int array_index);

#endif
```

And my C++ cpp file (abbreviated) looks like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
#include "DFSAlgorithm.h"//include definition of class DFSAlgorithm
using namespace std;

int adjacency[6];
stack<int> path; //stack to hold the last hex visited

//test printsomething
extern "C" void printSomething(){
    cout<<"Goobers2014";
}

//First call of DFS always starts with array_index ==  0
extern "C" int DFS(int color, int hex_array[], int array_index){    

    if (hex_array[array_index] == color){ //if hex has an appropriately colored stone

        hex_array[array_index] += 3;    //mark the hex as visited

        path.push(array_index); //push hex onto path stack
    }
    if ((color == 1 && array_index % 11 == 10 && hex_array[array_index] == 4) || 
        (color == 2 && array_index / 11 == 10 && hex_array[array_index] == 5)){

    return 1; //winner base case==>reached the other side
    }

//If a visited/unvisited hex has a stone of correct color==> search adjacent hexes
if ((color == 1 &&  hex_array[array_index] == 4)  || 
    (color == 2  &&  hex_array[array_index] == 5)){

    //get adjacencies
    //removed from code for brevity
        }

    /*Initialize adjacentHexes to zero: if == 0 after all 6 adjacencies are 
    checked it is a dead end as there are no unvisited adjacent hexes with 
    the correct color stone*/
    int adjacentHexes = 0;  
        for(int b = 0; b < 6; b++){//traverse adjacency array of passed in index

//if one of the adjacent hexes has a red/blue stone
    if((color == 1 && hex_array[adjacency[b]] == color) ||
    (color == 2 && hex_array[adjacency[b]] == color )){ 

        adjacentHexes++;    //increment adjacentHexes count

        hex_array[adjacency[b]] += 3;   //mark the hex as visited

        path.push(adjacency[b]); //push visited adjacent hex onto path 

        //recursively call DFS with that adjacent hex index
                return DFS(color, hex_array,adjacency[b]);  

                }
            }
        //If adjacentHexes == 0 ==> dead-end
                if(adjacentHexes == 0 && path.size() > 1){

        path.pop();//pop the top hex from the stack if stack > 1

        //recursive call of DFS with the new top red/blue hex
        return DFS(color, hex_array,path.top());
                    }
        if(adjacentHexes == 0 && path.size() == 1){//back to Row 0/Column 0

                    //make the array_index = the top of the path stack      
//+++++this line generates a "deque iterator not dereferenceable" error++++++++++++++
                    array_index = path.top();

                    //pop remaining element from the stack so path is now zero
                    path.pop();
                }
    }
        //if checking for a red path and path is empty
        if (color == 1 ){

            //search remaining column 0 hexes for unvisited red hex 
            for(array_index ; array_index <= 99; ){ 

                //recursively call DFS with next Column 0 hex
                return DFS(color, hex_array, array_index + 11);
                }
        }

        //if checking for a blue path and path is empty
        if (color == 2){

        //search remaining row 0 hexes for unvisted blue hex
            for(array_index ; array_index <= 9; ){

                //recursively call DFS with next Row 0 hex
                return DFS(color, hex_array, array_index + 1);
                }
            }
            //Traverse hex_array and reset all visited hexes to unvisited
            for(int a = 0; a < 121; a++){
                if(hex_array[a] >= 4)//if hex has been visited
                    hex_array[a] -= 3;//remove visited designation  
            }

        return -1;//return false as no path exists

}
```

I'm not sure why it fails on the line where I set the array_index to path.top() and then pop the top off the stack because it worked fine when the entire file was in C++ so I'm not sure why it is not working now.  I assume it has something to do with how the C++ function is accessing the array_index.

Comment: So I need to add a header file in my C++ program//DFS_Only.h
and then include it in my assembly like the irvine library?

Answer (score 3):

The error tells you the problem very clearly; you have no definition of global function `ShowBoard`.

If you were expecting `DFSAlgorithm::showBoard`'s definition, then you will be disappointed for two reasons:

1. `DFSAlgorithm::showBoard` is not a global function, but a member function (on which instance of `DFSAlgorithm` would it operate?);
2. `showBoard` and `ShowBoard` are spelt differently.

As for `main`, your C++ file should not define `main` because your assembly file does, and you only want *one* such definition across your program.

Comment: I still don't understand exactly what I need to do to get this working. I changed the call to showBoard in my MASM file, but I'm not sure how to create a "global function."  Do I need a c++ header?  Because I tried creating a header file, compiled the c++ program and added the .obj file to my VS project and I'm still getting two errors "DFSAlgorithm.obj : error LNK2011: precompiled object not linked in; image may not run
1>HexAssemblyTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _printSomething referenced in function _main@0"  I'm not sure what I need to do to "link" the obj file.

Comment: @user3355955: Do you know the difference between a global function and a member function?

Comment: a member function is inside a class?